# How to uninstall Postsharp or change it's licence when there is no Visual Studio installed?

Tags: msbuild, postsharp

I have installed Postsharp on my build server. There were only Microsoft Build Tools (MSBuild) without Visual Studio installed.

Now I need to change the license of the postsharp. When I run the installer, it 
says that the postsharp is already installed. There is no "Uninstall" option nor "Change licence". The official manual says that postsharp can be uninstalled with the Visual Studio extensions panel. Since I don't have Visual Studio installed, I'm wondering how to remove postsharp or change its licence.

Comment: Just additinal note that normally PostSharp doesn't require a license on a build server. It tries to detect the uanttended build run and then skips the license check. Also, you don't need to run PostSharp installer on a build server in most cases. Automatically restoring NuGet packages during build should be enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

If you open registry editor (regedit) and delete `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SharpCrafters\PostSharp 3`, postsharp will be reinstalled when you run installer.